# Add Mobile Search Icon next fa fa-bars Wordpress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, search, menu

Hello how to add search icon " icon-magnifier " next to  fa fa-bars in wordpress

The Icon show in Big Screen already but not in mobile version.

See picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOrg6.png

Comment: Share the code here. I will add search box in that code.

Comment: what page and code you mean ?